# TypeError when attempting to parse pubmed EFetch

Tags: biopython

I'm new to this python/biopyhton stuff, so am struggling to work out why the following code, pretty much lifted straight out of the Biopython Cookbook, isn't doing what I'd expect.

I'd have thought it'd end up with the interpreter display two list containing the same number, but all i get is one list and then a message saying *TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable*.

I'm guessing something is going wrong with the Medline.parse step and the result of the efetch isn't being processed in a way that allows subsequent interation to extract the PMID values. Or, the efetch isn't returning anything.

Any pointers at to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```
from Bio import Medline
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = 'A.N.Other@example.com'

handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="biopython")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
print(record['IdList'])

items = record['IdList']
handle2 = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=items, rettype="medline", retmode="text")
records = Medline.parse(handle2)
for r in records:
    print(records['PMID'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to print `records['PMID']` which is a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). I think you meant to do `print(r['PMID'])` which will print the 'PMID' entry in the current record dictionary object for each iteration. This is confirmed by the example given in the [`Bio.Medline.parse()`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Medline-module.html#parse) documentation.